# How to do a dynamic HTML-pagewidth, that jumps in 3 devicesteps on resize - without js?

Tags: css, dynamic, resize, width, html

I found [this Page](http://my.opera.com/community/) and after resizing windowwidth, it totally changed its css-values. I thought of Javascript, but it even does with JS disabled. If you resize the Page, it changes the width in 3 steps. The computed css-values shown by firebug or chrome are not affected, but you definitly see the change. I searched for some kind of media-query or something else, but there was nothing. Hope someone understands what's going on =) I'd like to use it instead of media-querys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are actually using media queries. You can easily check it out by searching in [their css](http://static.myopera.com/community/css/main.css) for `@media`, there are plenty of matches.